# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function WP_Filesystem()

Tags: fatal-error, 500-internal-error

"internal server error"

```
wp-content/themes/xxxxxx/inc/custom-functions.php on line 529
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143101/use-wp-filesystem-outside-wp-admin

Answer (score 7):

The error is in `custom-functions.php` line 529 where you might be using file system function outside of admin, you can fix this by including the core admin `file.php` file like this.

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
```